# Not sure what I am doing wrong - getting is not a function errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, but I have a few functions inside my component.  However, I'm not able to pass one of those functions down as a prop, I receive a `this.nextScene` is not a function.

Here's a snippet from my component, and I have commented out where I am having the issue:

```
  nextScene() {
    this.refs.navigator.push('browse');
  }

  renderNavigationView() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.drawer}>
        <Touchable
          onPress={this.nextScene()}     //issue here, "this.nextScene is not a function"
        >
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Browse</Text>
          </View>
        </Touchable>
        <Touchable>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Button</Text>
          </View>
        </Touchable>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <DrawerLayoutAndroid
        ref="drawer"
        drawerWidth={300}
        drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
        renderNavigationView={this.renderNavigationView}>
        <Navigator
          ref="navigator"
          configureScene={(route) => {
            if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
              return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottomAndroid;
            }
          } }
          initialRoute={{}}
          renderScene={this.renderScene}
          />
      </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
    );
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want to pass reference, not an invocation - also you might need to bind this or use an arrow function because `this` isn't the right context as it's window

Comment: Hi.  So if I try `this.nextScene.bind(this)`, I get a `cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the component you are rendering, and at the `renderNavigationView` prop:

```
renderNavigationView={this.renderNavigationView}
```

It seems fine, but since the `this` context in functions is `window` by default, `this` refers to `window` in `renderNavigationView`. Consider your `onPress` event handler:

```
onPress={this.nextScene()}
```

Since you use `this.nextScene()` and `this` refers to `window` in a function, you're effectively trying to do `window.nextScene` which does not exist, thus throwing the error. (Also note that that is an invocation - not a reference. Remove the parentheses).

---

> So if I try `this.nextScene.bind(this)`, I get a `cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

This is because the function is undefined because `window.nextScene` doesn't exist. To fix this, use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the `this` correctly on *both* `renderNavigationView` and `nextScene`:

```
renderNavigationView={this.renderNavigationView.bind(this)}
```

What `bind` does in this situation is set the `this` context in the function. Since `this` here refers to the class, the class will be used to execute the `nextScene` method which should work correctly. You must also use bind on `nextScene` because inside `nextScene` we want `this` to refer to the *class*, not `window`:

```
onPress={this.nextScene.bind(this)}
```

Comment: Wow!  Thanks so much!  The explanation really helped me to understand where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to using the bind method that winter pointed out in his answer is to use arrow functions which automatically bind `this` to the parent context for you.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  clickHandler = (e) => {
    // do stuff here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.clickHandler}></button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Nit-pick: arrow functions don't automatically bind `this` - they don't even bind it. Because they don't bind it, `this` refers to the enclosing context.

Comment: Hmm...I'm not sure about that. I'm going to look that up. Since an arrow function is still a function, the way javascript works it seems like internally it would have to bind to the parent context...if it didn't bind it would work the same as declaring a regular anonymous function which, even though you're not explicitly binding it, still has it's own context, one not of the parent. I'm going to look this up though.

Comment: *An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and does not bind its own this* - from [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/my/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)